# zlib lib-compression with uninitialized values

Tags: c, linux

I'm running into problem when trying to install dovecot from source into my ubuntu server 12.04.5 32bit.

```
Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
    at 0x4046DD8: inflateReset2 (in /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.3.4)
    by 0x4046EC7: inflateInit2_ (in /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.3.4)
    by 0x804B16F: i_stream_zlib_init (istream-zlib.c:320)
    by 0x804B2A2: i_stream_create_zlib (istream-zlib.c:475)
    by 0x804AB98: test_compression_handler (test-compression.c:72)
    by 0xEFCDAB88: ???

make[2]: *** [check-test] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/dovecot-2.2.16/src/lib-compression'
make[1]: *** [check-recursive] Error 1
```

I have tried the solution below:

```
$ cd /usr/local/src/dovecot-2.2.16
$ cat << EOF > ./run-test-valgrind.supp
{
   <squeezy-zlib-uninitialized>
   Memcheck:Cond
   fun:inflateReset2
   fun:inflateInit2_
   fun:i_stream_zlib_init
   fun:i_stream_create_zlib
   fun:test_compression_handler
   fun:test_compression
   fun:test_run_funcs
   fun:test_run
   fun:main
}
EOF
```

But I'm still getting the same error message as above.

Any help would be great.

Thank you

Comment: If you're sure it is a general problem in zlib, then stop the suppression trace at the top of zlib: `fun:i_stream_create_zlib`.  The other entries stop the suppression being useful except in your current test program.  I assume you got that entry from `--gen-suppressions=yes` or thereabouts.    But are you sure the problem is in zlib and not in your code?  It seems more likely to me that you've made a mistake and passed something that's incorrectly initialized into the zlib code, leading to the message you see.  Be very wary of blaming your tools for your own problems.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The answer is no - I'm not sure if this error got to do with zlib. All I know is I got no such error when installing dovecot-2.2.12. But again the problem would be with my system as I don't see many users with the same error I got :(

Comment: Assume the problem is in your code (or the dovecot code) and not in zlib until you're absolutely sure you've no alternative.  Only then consider using the suppression you show.  And consider updating zlib if that is where the problem actually is.

Answer (score 0):

Since the "solution" (which seems to be the "official" fix for dovecot) just suppresses valgrind's complaints (and you do not seem to be interested in these anyway), you'd probably get away easiest by just temporarily deinstalling valgrind (and reinstall it afterwards) for your build.

This will just disable the tests and won't fix the error obviously, but will get you going.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, I need to enable valgrind for my dovecot pigeonhole sieve. After further more digging, I found the reason why deflate is performing a conditional jump that depends on an uninitialized value - This only started showing up recently since zlib 1.2.x uses malloc() by default for allocations, whereas earlier versions used calloc(), which zeros out the allocated memory. Even though the code was correct, versions 1.2.4 and later was changed to not stimulate these checkers. Hence, I need to find a way to check the version of zlib on my ubuntu 12.04 :(